# Pygame built-in automatic pause?

Tags: python, pygame

I just recently learned Python and Pygame library.

I noticed that the rendering and main loop is automatically paused when I click and hold on the window menu bar (the bar with the title/icon).

For example, in a snake game, the snake will be moving every frame. When I click and hold (or drag) the window menu, the snake is not moving anymore and the game is "paused". When I release it, it resumes.

Is there a way to let the game NOT pause when I drag the windows menu bar?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10122289/why-does-pygame-freeze-at-pygame-event-get-when-you-move-drag-the-window

Comment: I think the short answer is that you cannot stop it from pausing.

Answer (score 2):

When you drag the window only the event queue gets stopped.
So if your update/draw is not coupled with the event queue,
they will not be paused.

```
from pygame.locals import *
import pygame
import sys

import time;
import random;

pygame.init()
DISPLAYSURF = pygame.display.set_mode((530, 212))

while True:
    t = random.random();
    t *= 255;
    for event in pygame.event.get():        
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
        print event;

    DISPLAYSURF.fill((int(t) % 255, int(t) % 255, int(t) % 255));
    pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score -1):

This one is pretty easy, its seems you forgot to add a event callback.
state 1
        while (sate != 0):
           for event in pygame.event.get():

Comment: This answer doesn't make any sense to me.