# Pygame : The game stops temporarily when I am moving the window

Tags: python, pygame, drag-and-drop, window, code-freeze

I'm a new in PyGame and I was making a game. Until I discovered that when you were moving the window to another place of your desktop for example, the game temporarily stops. But ticks of the game still running when I used pygame.time.get_ticks().

So I made a completely new program with only the necessary code and it does the same thing.

Can someone explain me why it does it and if we can resolve this problem?

```
import pygame

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800,600))
pygame.display.set_caption('The Test Program')

running = True
update_counter = 1

while running:
  for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
      running = False

  pygame.display.flip()
  print(str(update_counter) + " updates")
  update_counter += 1


pygame.quit()
quit()
# So try to move the window across your screen and you will see that, prints will stop and they will resume when you will release the click
```

Comment: when I run on Linux Mint (with PyGame 1.9.6) then it prints all time - so it may depends on system which you use. Maybe some systems stop running code when you move window - and maybe it is normal thing in your system.

Comment: While also not having a clear answer, this is the same question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10122289/why-does-pygame-freeze-at-pygame-event-get-when-you-move-drag-the-window

Answer (score 0):

So someone tell me that was normal, so I think it's only on Windows but there are no solutions. I put a script that show a pause symbol on screen when the cursor leave the window to make it normal.